# Calculate time to decelerate using initial speed and decay

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, animation, actionscript

I'm trying to calculate the time it will take a movieclip in Flash to decelerate to zero. The starting speed will vary, but for purpose of example lets say:

Frames Per Second: 30

Speed: 50

Decay: .8 * current speed each frame

```
onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    movieClip.x += speed;
    speed *= .8;

}
```

How would I figure out the time in seconds or in total frames it would take to decelerate to zero?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that what you call acceleration is actually speed. You do decelerate it however (acceleration is change in speed). </nitpick>

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you call acceleration is in fact speed/velocity in pixels per frame.

Starting from the very first frame (i-th) when you start adjusting velocity by a factor of 0.8 you can express the velocity as:

**v(i) = v(i-1) * 0.8**
and **v(0) = 50**

You can reexpress v(i) using v(0) as:

**v(i) = v(0) * 0.8<sup>i</sup>**

I can think of 2 different stop conditions:

**1. v(i) < 1** (meaning: velocity drops below 1 px/frame)
**2. v(i) - v(i+1) < 0.1** (meaning: velocity changes by less than 0.1 px between frames)

**For the first you get:**

v(0) * 0.8<sup>i</sup> < 1

0.8<sup>i</sup> < 1 / v(0)

i > log0.8(1 / v(0))

changing the logarithm base using logb(x) = loga(x) / loga(b):

**i > ln(1 / v(0)) / ln(0.8)**

i > ln(1 / 50) / ln(0.8)

i > 17.531

**For the second you get:**

v(0)*0.8<sup>i</sup> - v(0)*0.8<sup>i+1</sup> < 0.1

v(0)*0.8<sup>i</sup> - v(0)*0.8<sup>i</sup> * 0.8 < 0.1

v(0)*0.8<sup>i</sup> * (1 - 0.8) < 0.1

0.8<sup>i</sup> < 0.1 / (v(0) * (1 - 0.8))

i > log0.8(0.1 / (v(0) * (1 - 0.8)))

**i > ln(0.1 / (v(0) * (1 - 0.8))) / ln(0.8)**

i > ln(0.1 / (50 * (1 - 0.8))) / ln(0.8)

i > 20.638

So, with these numbers you get about 20 frames worth of time till the movement stops. 
Tweak the numbers as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to stare at this over a bottle of wine in hopes that a light goes of in my brain allowing me to convert your advanced (to me) math to ActionScript.

Comment: @forrex: ln() calculates natural logarithm (base e, where e=2.71828...). You should have something in ActionScript to do basic arithmetic and calculate logarithms.